# django rest framework with aws s3

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm saving my files in an aws s3. When I make a get request, I get this:

```
{
"id": 5,
"imageName": "testImage2",
"url": "https://smartsight-storage.s3.amazonaws.com/image/testImage2-Picture1.png?AWSAccessKeyId=asd&Signature=ads
}
```

It should not share `AWSAccessKeyId=asd&Signature=ads`. How can I remove it from the response?

Comment: I am not sure if you are performing the get request from django or if you are calling django endpoint with a get request... can you please provide the code and performs/handles the get request?

Comment: i'm using simple viewset of django rest_framework with a serializer and a queryset